# MySQL: Get ID if exists, else insert and return ID

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, insert

I am trying to construct a single query which will return the ID of the specified NAME record, or if it does not exist then insert the name and return the ID.  (ID is an autoincrement field, NAME will not have duplicates but is a varchar 1024 so it cannot have the unique attribute)

My SQL query should be something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM NAMES WHERE NAME='DAVE')
THEN
    SELECT FROM NAMES WHERE NAME='DAVE'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO NAMES(`NAME`) VALUES ('DAVE')
ENDIF;
```

(obviously this is not valid SQL...but I'm not sure where to begin)

Example NAMES table:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | NAME     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | ANDY     |
| 2  | BOB      |
| 3  | CARL     |
+----+----------+
```

Should I just split this into multiple queries?

Comment: do an insert ignore, then a select. though i wonder if there's a way to skip the select too.

Comment: since I can't use unique (sinces varchar > 1000 cant use unique), then insert ignore will just add duplicates

Comment: You can split this into two queries. One for inserting if the record is not present and the other to actually get the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the task you are trying to achieve :

1. First check if there exists a row with the specific name
2. If yes, select the entire row and retrieve the id ,if no insert the data into db.

You can use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() after your insert operation to get the id of the newly inserted row.

Comment: Looks like no way to do this in a single query, so I'll split it